# Hilt injection with android instrumented tests

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, dagger-hilt, android-instrumentation

I am running into the following exception when running a test for a composable that injects a hilt view model, eg:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
   viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
}
```

Following the hilt testing documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing

I have the following test:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyComposeTest {

   @get:Rule(order = 0)
   var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

   @get:Rule(order = 1)
   val composeRule = createComposeRule()

   @Before
   fun setup() {
      hiltRule.inject()
   }

   @Test
   fun canary() {
    // This test fails with exception
   }
}
```

With a custom test runner:

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

Use in build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Replace com.example.android.dagger with your class path.
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.android.dagger.CustomTestRunner"
    }
}
```

Looks like the first place it dies is in my AppInitializer, which handle androidx.startup initialization.

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface AppInitializer {

   companion object {
      // Resolve the InitializerEntryPoint from a context
      fun resolve(context: Context): AppInitializer {
         val appContext = context.applicationContext ?: throw IllegalStateException()
         return EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
            appContext,
            AppInitializer::class.java
         )
      }
   }

   fun inject(workManagerInitializer: WorkManagerInitializer)
   fun inject(otherInitializer: OtherInitializer)
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.
    at dagger.hilt.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:83)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.TestApplicationComponentManager.generatedComponent(TestApplicationComponentManager.java:96)
    at dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltTestApplication.generatedComponent(HiltTestApplication.java:50)
    at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:59)
    at dagger.hilt.android.EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(EntryPointAccessors.kt:35)
    at com.test.AppInitializer$Companion.resolve(AppInitializer.kt:27)
```

**EDIT:**

To get past this I had to use *@EarlyEntryPoint* and *EarlyEntryPoints.get(appContext, AppInitializer::class.java)*.

That did get me further, however I am still running into an issue with hilt injecting the viewmodel into the composable.  eg

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
   viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.test.MyViewModel
```

Given my setup should hilt properly inject the viewModel into the composable?  Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Is the test runner package defined correctly? "com.example.android.dagger.CustomTestRunner"

Comment: I believe so, I put a log statement in the newApplication which I see in the logs before the crash.